# Is it possible to make this code shorter?

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code:

```
var newPositions = new Array(count);
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    newPositions[i] = i;
                }
```

Is it possible to init this array from 0 to count more quickly(in one-line I mean)?
**upd:** 
count is a number that may differ in execution time

**upd2:** dont think about algorithm, only way to write this code in one-line. 
As @Martin Jespersen suggest and using somebody deleted answer:

```
for (var i = 0, newPositions = []; i < count; newPositions[i] = i++)
```

Comment: What's the count come from? What's it's value?

Comment: @ hunter: I rename my topic to match what I mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0,newPositions=[]; i < count; i++) {
  newPositions[i] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a way to optimize that any more :)

Answer (score 1):

That's about as 'easy' as it gets to do what you want; the only potential optimisation is to turn the array initialisation into a function, like so:

```
function range(count) {
    var countArray = new Array(count);
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        countArray[i] = i;
    }
    return countArray;
}
```

Then assign it to your variable:

```
var newPositions = range(count);
```

Only an optimisation if you needed to do that a reasonable number of times, to account for the additional time spent coding the function. If it's being done once then it's about as good as it's going to get.

As a sort of aside, the code you have initialises newPositions from 0 to count-1, rather than 0 to count, due to the way your for loop is set up. Change `i < count` to `i <= count` in your for loop if you want to include the value of count in your array.

Answer (score 0):

If count is always a known number, then the syntax for creating a javascript array in 1 line is

```
var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; //assuming count was 8
```

Answer (score 0):

The smart-ass answer would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) newPositions[i] = i;
```

But a better answer (or question) would be: Why is this array useful to you at all? The array is holding values that can be easily calculated on the fly. With more information we can give you a better answer.

Comment: You are missing the newPosition declaration, arrays need to be created before use.

Comment: After initialization I shuffle it

Comment: Yes... I figured (I guess wrongly) that a subset of the original code would be understandable. I was assuming he know that the declaration couldn't be optimized unless "count" is constant. The loop is his main concern to which there is no optimization that can be applied. His problem is his algorithm, not his code.

Comment: @Kai Then your optimization should be to shuffle while you initialize instead of doing it in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

Not much easier i'm afraid unless you alwasy use the same count as in Jamiec's answer.

```
var newPositions = [];
while(count-- > 0)
     newPositions[count] = count;
```

This is a little shorter but the same code except it changes cout so maybe use a temp var fpor that instead.

Comment: you don't need the `> 0` part using a reverse loop like this. Anyway like I already mentioned, it will be reversed!

Comment: @jAndy: What will be reversed?